# Получить абсолютный URL из относительного

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Есть такой код:

```
requests.get(img.get('src'))
```

Он работал, пока были абсолютные урлы в HTML. Сейчас урлы относительные, то есть без домена.

Как дополнить этот код чтобы учитывало домен и урл для скачивания картинки был правильным в итоге?

Comment: Я так подозреваю, вопрос нужно переформулировать как «Получить абсолютный URL из относительного»?

Comment: @andreymal точно

Answer (score 4):

В питон встроена функция `urljoin` для этой задачи.

Для корректной обработки относительных путей вам следует знать адрес страницы, с которой вы достали `img`. Предполагаю, что он вам известен.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

# Первый аргумент — адрес страницы, на которой ваша картинка
# Второй аргумент — ваш img.get('src')

>>> urljoin('http://example.com', 'foo.jpg')
'http://example.com/foo.jpg'

>>> urljoin('http://example.com/foo1/foo2/', '../bar/foo.jpg')
'http://example.com/foo1/bar/foo.jpg'

>>> urljoin('http://example.com/foo1/foo2/', '/root/foo.jpg')
'http://example.com/root/foo.jpg'

>>> urljoin('http://example.com/page/index.html', 'foo.jpg')
'http://example.com/page/foo.jpg'

>>> urljoin('http://example.com/foo', 'https://другойдомен.рф/картинка.png')
'https://другойдомен.рф/картинка.png'
```

(В Python 2 есть `urlparse.urljoin`, но там она немножко баганута; [подробнее на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476521))

Answer (score 1):

Ну если вопрос был понят мною верно, то нужно добавить этот самый домен

```
requests.get( "http://example.com/" + img.get('src'))
```

**Обратите внимание что данный ответ зависим от структуры передаваемых дынных.**

1. Относительный путь должен начинаться с корня сайта
2. Если домен динамический и изменяется в процессе выполнения программы
   лучшим решением будет хранить **абсолютный** путь.

Comment: Если картинка расположена на странице `http://example.com/foo1/foo2/` и ссылка прописана на `../bar/baz.jpg`, то адрес картинки будет `http://example.com/foo1/bar/baz.jpg`, а в вашем варианте получится `http://example.com/../bar/baz.jpg`, так что не всё так просто

Comment: Да спасибо, работает

Comment: @user184069 , однажды сломается, я гарантирую это

Comment: @andreymal, если домен изменяется, то решения просто нет. В таком случае необходимо ведь хранить и сам домен, так что ваш пример не совсем корректен, но я добавлю замечание в ответ.